# How to handle with all uncaught errors on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, next.js

I have researched handling errors on React. I have read Error Boundaries in original React Documents.
But Error boundaries do not catch errors for:

1. Event handlers
2. Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)
3. Server side rendering Errors thrown
4. in the error boundary itself.

How can i catch all of that errors? Is there a package etc. to handle errors?

Comment: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary#useerrorhandlererror-unknown